# Both time work for me , or Both time works for me, or Both times work for me?

Tags: grammaticality

which one is grammatically  correct ?

**Both time work for me  , or Both time works for me, or Both times work for me ?**

I think  the answer is : **Both time work for me**

Although **time** is always singular word, here the **Both** makes it plural ! Am I correct?

Thank you.

Comment: 'Both times' is correct for scheduling appointments. If 2AM and 3 are good time slots, then both times work for me. Both and Times go together, but the two time slots are what calls for 'both'. Both does not drive Times, the two time slots do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your sentence **Both time work for me** is almost correct.

Because you modify the word **time** with the quantifier **both** it then becomes **plural = times**

Times refers to  two specific points in time that are agreed upon for meeting.

The subject of the sentence  **= Both times** which is a plural **subject** which must then agree with a plural verb **= work **NOT** works.**

Final result= **Both times work for me.**

I hope that helps.

Comment: I don't know who voted down, the question and right answers  at same time, Without caring to put a comment !

Thanks,  So based  your explanation , we can say (for example): 
**Both works are fine** not **Both work are fine**

Comment: Yosef, thank you for your comments.  Yes, I'm not sure about all this voting business.  I just care about helping folks. Both works doesn't make sense as works in this sense isn't a clear noun to be modified.  Here is another example: Both books are fine.

Comment: @Redshoes A bit late to the party - regarding your comment, a quick search shows "Both works are fine" is correct. I saw a few use cases in New York Times. Reference: https://ludwig.guru/s/both+works

Answer (score 1):

"Both times work for me" is the correct phrase.